# SidePanel css react-burger-menu

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a sidepanel implemented using react-burger-menu and I am having some issues with the styles. I am manually setting a padding-left to the pageContent to shift it to the right when the sidepanel is open (which I feel is wrong). And keeping the sidepanel open, if I scroll the whole overlay scrolls. I just want the pageContent to scroll. Please advice.

P.S: I also have bootstrap here.

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-5yhmax?file=Navbar%2FNavbar.tsx)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you mean the heading should be visible on the top though you scroll the page down?

Comment: Not the heading. If you see this link https://react-ts-5yhmax.stackblitz.io/, please open the sidebar using the button and scroll. There is a small css glitch on the top and I hope to fix it.

Comment: for this class `.bp3-navbar ` try giving `position:fixed`